# AND+OR function not working as supposed to

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010

I've got the following formula

```
 =IF((AND(OR(AND($D5<-9;$F5>=150;$H5>=150);
AND($D5<-6;$F5>=185;$F5>190));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"MEAC"));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"AE"));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"Asun"));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"BSth"));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"SWAC"));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"Pat"));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"NEC"));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"Slnd"));
NOT(EXACT(I5;"C-USA"))));
B5&" +"&ABS(D5);" ")
```

What I want it to do is

```
IF $D5<-9;$F5>=150;$H5>=150 OR $D5<-6;$F5>=185;$H5>190
```

`AND` if one of the above is True, filter for the `NOT(EXACT` strings

Should I use `AND(AND(AND` instead of `AND(OR(AND` ?
I know the formula looks messy but I'm not an excel wizard.

EDIT: added screenshot
So for good measure:
Both rankings should be above 150 and opening line should be above -9,5 
BUT if both rankings are above 190 (185 for away team) then the opening line should only be -6,5 to qualify as a good value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxeUz.png)

Comment: F5 appears twice in one ff your OR tests. Does that matter? What's the issue?

Comment: If I read this thing, you are testing whether at the same time, your OR statement is true and ALL of the NOT(EXACT) statements are true.
I do not think this was what you intended. If it was, then the code should work as intended. Can you provide details as to what's going wrong?

P.s. I think Doug means you mistakenly used F5 instead of H5 in the second-hand test of the OR statement

Comment: It's for putting a treshold, F5 and H5 are rankings
If they are both above 150 and D5 is below -9 then it's okay
BUT if F5 and H5 are both above 190 then D5 sould only be below -6,5
the NOT(EXACT) statements are just a filter really.

Comment: What about the issue I mentioned with F5 appearing twice in one OR. Sure looks like a typo.

Comment: Well that's not the problem as I need two treshold values out of that column , I added a screenshot

Comment: Testing `$F5>=185;$F5>190` is the same as just doing the first part of the test. It can't be greater than 185 and not be greater than 190.

Comment: Oh that typo , yes indeed that's a typo , sorry I thought you ment in the formula.

Comment: Oh there it is wrong too, wow i'm such a retard. Sorry. Thanks for spotting it, I would have gone desperate !

Comment: Glad to help. Also, an SO hint: co like "@Doug Glancy" in your comment to have SO let me know.